# How can I prevent my instant on hot water heater from starving my furnace of gas?

Tags: water, furnace, heater, natural-gas

How can I prevent my instant on hot water heater from starving my furnace of gas? Just installed a new tankless water heater. I have 1 inch gas line going to 3/4 inch gas line reduced to 5/8 gas line to the water heater love it. it works excellently.

The problem is and I have observed this to be true. When I turn on the hot water after about 30 seconds my pilot light in my furnace flickers and goes out. To my furnace I have a 3/4 inch gas pipe from the meter reduced to a half inch to a brand new gas valve and a brand new pilot and brand new thermal pile. As long as I don’t turn on the hot water this works all day long.

This is how bad it is I can be taking a shower in the morning with the furnace on, because it’s cold now, and the furnace goes out . I’m not talking about the pilot light at this point I’m talking about the furnace fully rockin hot and it simply goes out. When I turn the hot water heater on. This to me indicates that the hot water heater is starving my furnace from natural gas. How do I solve that problem???!

Comment: Seems like you might need to talk to your gas supplier about the supply to your house/meter, if the two appliances don't share pipe from the meter.

Comment: Sounds like your gas supply is failing from the load of the on-demand heater.  On-demands take a LOT of gas.  For instance our 135,000 BTU unit is sized for a small 1bath cottage. An electric unit of same capacity would need a 200A service *dedicated to it*.